# property 'filter', 'pagination', 'sort' 'doesn't exist on the userdatasource

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have created a table with pagination, sort, and filter using Angular Material with static JSON data. It's working fine below is my source code URL [Code URL working with static Json](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pagination-table-working2-test).

But I am trying to convert into service but it's showing Typo like "property 'filter', 'pagination', 'sort' 'doesn't exist on the userdatasource(in architecturetiles.ts)". Below is my URL code getting error [Code URL not working sort filter pagination using service](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pagination-table-working2-test2).
Please help on this?
[image]

Comment: where do you get the json? where is this line?

Comment: It is available on assets/data/customer.json. Please check enterprise interface